Explanation Request - Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis proof that $\sqrt 2$ exists
In Abbott's proof for existence of $\sqrt{2}$, he takes the following steps (which completely, utterly, totally baffle me):
Choose  as an upper bound for the set $T = \{t∈\mathbb R:t^2<2\}$ such that $ = \sup T$. He says that the assumption $^2<2$ violates our fact that  is an upper bound. He goes on to prove this by writing:
$(+\frac 1n)^2=^2+\frac {2}{} +\frac {1}{^2}$
$2<^2+\frac {2}{}+\frac {1}{}$
$=^2+\frac{2+1}{}$
Choose $n_0$
such that
$\frac {1}{_0}<\frac {2−^2}{2+1}$.
Which implies: $\frac {2+1}{n_0} < 2-^2$, which consequently implies:
$(+ \frac {1}{n_0})^2 < ^2 + (2-^2)=2$, which contradicts the fact that  is an upper bound for T.
I have no earthly idea what he did to get here, why he picked the fraction $\frac 1n$, or how he concluded what he concluded. This has been the first proof in the book to totally baffle me. In addition, proving that $^2 > 2$ is left as an exercise for the reader. Safe to say I have no idea how to do that one either. Could someone please break it down for me in more detail and maybe mention what theorems were used?
Edit: fixed a typo in the first line. The term $\frac {1}{n^2}$ was $\frac 1n$ by accident.

Another way to do it would be: if $\alpha^2 > 2$, and you set $\beta := (\alpha + \frac{2}{\alpha}) / 2$, then $\beta < \alpha$ and $\beta^2 > 2$.  Similarly, if $\alpha^2 < 2$, and you set $\beta := 2 / [(\alpha + \frac{2}{\alpha}) / 2]$, then $\beta > \alpha$ and $\beta^2 < 2$.  Of course, that method is very specific to the square root case, or maybe could be generalized to the $n$th root case; whereas Stephen Abbott's method generalizes nicely to a proof of the intermediate value theorem i.e. the case of any continuous function.

The goal is to show that $\alpha^2 = 2$, which we do by excluding the cases $\alpha^2 < 2$ and $\alpha^2 > 2$.
If $\alpha^2<2$, the idea is to find some slightly bigger number than $\alpha^2$, but still in $T$. This would contradict our choice of $\alpha$. The reals have the Archimedean property, meaning that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $n\in \mathbb{R}$ with $0<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. In other words, $\frac{1}{n}$ can be made arbitrarily small, which makes it an apt choice for our scenario. So we consider $(\alpha+\frac{1}{n})^2 = \alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$. By definition, $\alpha =\sup T$ so
$$2< \alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Hence,
$$
2-\alpha^2 <\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n} = \frac{2\alpha+1}{n}
$$
(I think there was a typo of yours here, where did the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ go?, but we are fine by letting $n>1$, which is fine since $n$ is as large as we like). Rearranging to isolate the $\frac{1}{n}$ term, we have
$$
\frac{2-\alpha^2 }{2\alpha+1}<\frac{1}{n}.
$$
This is where we use the Archimedean property to find $n_0$ large enough to have
$$
\frac{2-\alpha^2 }{2\alpha+1}>\frac{1}{n_0}.
$$
Rearranging, we have
$$
{2-\alpha^2 }>\frac{2\alpha+1}{n_0}.
$$
Then
$$(\alpha+\frac{1}{n_0})^2 < \alpha^2 + \frac{2\alpha+1}{n_0}<2,$$
a contradiction to the definition of $\alpha$.
This gives us $\alpha^2\geq 2$. To show that $\alpha^2 = 2$, we need to show that $\alpha^2\not>2$. The same type of reasoning works here too, by now analyzing $(\alpha-\frac{1}{n})^2$.

Let's take a numerical example:

Suppose $\alpha = 1.4$. Then $\alpha^2= 1.96 <2$.

The aim is to find some larger number whose square is also less than $2$.

Following the argument, we would then have $\frac {2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}=\frac1{95}$, so we can choose any $n_0 >95$.

$n_0=100$ is a nice round number so let's choose that.

You would then say $1.4^2 < (1.4+\frac{1}{100})^2= 1.41^2= 1.9881 < 2$.

So this shows $\alpha=1.4$ is not $\sup\{T:T^2 <2\}$.


The proof itself says any $\alpha$ with $\alpha^2<2$ is not $\sup\{T:T^2 <2\}$ since there will be something else bigger than $\alpha$ with a square less than $2$.  You could use the same $\frac {2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}$ term and say this is shown $($at least for $\alpha> 1)$ by $$\alpha^2<\left(\alpha+\frac {2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}\right)^2 =2 -(2-\alpha^2)\frac{(\alpha^2+2\alpha-1)}{(2\alpha+1)^2} < 2$$ but Abbott gives a motivation for choosing this term by looking for a suitable reciprocal of a sufficiently large number to add than just plucking the expression  out of the air.

Abbott wants to show that the statement $\alpha^2<2$ contradicts the statement that that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $T$.
In other words, if $\alpha^2<2$ then $\alpha$ is not an upper bound of $T$.
So here's the overall structure of the proof: we assume $\alpha^2 < 2$ and that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $T$, and then we show a contradiction.
The specific contradiction is that $\alpha$ is not an upper bound of $T$.
What do we mean when we say $\alpha$ is not an upper bound of $T$? We mean that there is some other number $\beta$ that also is an element of $T$ and is greater than $\alpha$.
If that's true, then all we need to do to prove it is to find one such number that we can call $\beta$. But we need to show both that $\beta > \alpha$ and that $\beta \in T$.
The entire rest of the proof is meant to do this for some number $\beta$ of the form $\alpha + \frac1n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. It's vital that we know that $n$ is positive, because that's how we know that $\alpha + \frac1n > \alpha$.
To finish, Abbot just needs to show that if we make $n$ large enough,
$\left(\alpha + \frac1n\right)^2 < 2$ and therefore $\alpha + \frac1n \in T$.
Through some algebra, Abbot shows that if we find $n$ such that
$\dfrac1n < \dfrac{2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}$,
then $\left(\alpha + \frac1n\right)^2 < 2$.
(I don't know why Abbott names this number $n_0$. We only need one value of $n$ to finish the proof.)
Since we must have $\dfrac{2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1} > 0$
(which comes from the assumptions that $\alpha^2<2$ and that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $T$),
the Archimedean principle tells us that if we just choose a large enough $n$,
then $0 < \dfrac1n < \dfrac{2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}$.
So now we know there is an $n$ such that $0 < \dfrac1n < \dfrac{2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}$,
therefore $\dfrac1n < \dfrac{2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}$,
therefore $\left(\alpha + \frac1n\right)^2 < 2$,
therefore $\alpha + \frac1n \in T$.
And since we already know that $\alpha + \frac1n > \alpha$,
that means $\alpha$ is not an upper bound of $T$.

To really cover all the bases, note the statement that
$\dfrac{2−\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1} > 0$.
This is true if the numerator and denominator of the fraction have the same sign.
The assumption $\alpha^2 < 2$ implies that $2−\alpha^2$ is positive,
so we need to know that $2\alpha+1$ also is positive. How?
Pick a positive number that you know is in $T$. For example, consider the number $1$.
$1^2 < 2$, so $1$ is in $T$. We assumed $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $T$, which implies that $\alpha \geq 1$, which implies that $2\alpha+1 \geq 3$,
so $2\alpha+1$ is positive, which was what we needed to show.
It's unclear from your presentation whether Abbott covered this detail.

Suppose $a^2<2$ with $a>0$. For $r>0$, note $$(a+r)^2=a^2+2ar+r^2 \leq a^2+4ar\,,$$ since without loss of generality, we may assume $2ar \geq r^2$. If you want to be explicit, choose $r\in (0,2a]$. Now simply choose $r$ so that $4ar \leq 2-a^2$, that is, choose $r < (2-a^2)/(4a)$.
Putting it all together, choose $r < \min(2a,(2-a^2)/4a)$. Then
$$(a+r)^2 = a^2+2ar+r^2 \leq a^2+2ar+r\cdot2a = a^2+4ar < a^2+(2-a^2) = 2\,.$$

To begin with, I think you have a typo in the second line—Abbott says
$$\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2=\alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}< \alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n}= \alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha+1}{n}$$
But does not comment on the relationship of 2 to this.
This is important because the goal is to find some value which totals to less than 2, since  the approach is to find some value which is greater than $\alpha$ and yet its square is still less than 2, i.e. find a value that is in T but greater than $\alpha$.
As Andrew mentioned, the reason why we pick $\frac{1}{n}$ is because it is easy to see that by Archimedean property that we can always pick some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<r$ for any $r\in\mathbb{R}, r>0$.
And here is where that comes in. Since we can be assured that $\frac{2-\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}$ is a real number, it follows that we can find some $n_0$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n_0}<\frac{2-\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}\implies \frac{2\alpha+1}{n_0}<2-\alpha^2
$$
By plugging this into what we had originally,
$$
\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{n_0}\right)^2=\alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha}{n_0}+\frac{1}{n_0^2}< \alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha}{n_0}+\frac{1}{n_0}= \alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha+1}{n_0}<\alpha^2+(2-\alpha^2)=2
$$
But then since we have defined $\frac{1}{n_0}$ to be positive, we know
$$
\alpha<\alpha+\frac{1}{n_0}
$$
And since T is defined as
$$
T=\{t\in T:t^2<2\}
$$
We have found a value $\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{n_0}\right)\in T$, with $\alpha+\frac{1}{n_0}>\alpha$, which contradicts $\alpha$ being an upper bound of T.
